# Replace specific character from the list of string

Tags: python-2.7

Gurus,

I have list which looks like following :

```
[u'test1', u'test2', '', '']
```

I am trying to find a way to replace character u which is before 'test1' and 'test2' with none ''. So after replacing it will look like:

```
['test1','test2', '', '']
```

Initially I had list like following:

```
[u'test1\n', u'test2\r\n', '', '']
```

This I could reduce using following:

```
row_val = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in row_val]
row_val = [w.replace('\r', '') for w in row_val]
```

Let me know there is a way to perform the same without iterating through each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u` is not a string character, it is telling you that it is a `unicode` object rather than a `str` object.

You can just do:

```
row_val = [str(w) for w in row_val]
```